# Capacitive dropper

Tags: voltage, power

I was messing around with the idea of making capacitive dropper as a power supply for my project...

Power lines in my country carry 220 V ac 50Hz

And i would need to convert that into 4-14v
Current is going to be unable around 90-140mA

i have seen few designs of capacitive droppers on internet - but this pretty high tolerance to voltage instability could bring new innovative designs! (smaller?)

Comment: Are you aware of the safety implications of this type of supply and why it can be a very bad idea?

Comment: this device lacks of human ingerface, I wouldn't suggest using a dropper if that was so

Comment: Most of capacitive dropping circuits in white goods equipments are now replaced by ac-dc floating buck converters offering better reliability and efficiency. However, as highlighted by John D, these are non-isolated designs and I would recommend to build a small flyback converter with a UL-compliant transformer from a serious manufacturer instead. A primary-side regulated version is quite easy to build and schematics abound in the web.

Comment: And Your question is?

Comment: Agree with @JakubRakus - there are some statements made but no question posed. What is your actual, specific question?

Comment: Who the heck voted up a question that has *no question in it??*

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea.  Very, very bad.  Galvanic isolation is used so ubiquitously in mains powered products and required by so many regulatory bodies in various countries for a darn good reason, safety.

> but this device lacks of (sic) human interface

It does not matter, *you* will be touching it, and there are still potentially other hazards such as fires that can occur if a design isn't done properly.

> (I) am aware of the dangers that come with transformerless power supplies

I intend no offense, but I highly doubt this based on the terms you are using and your problem description.  I only say this for your safety.

> i have seen few designs of capacitive droppers on internet - but this pretty >high tolerance to voltage instability could bring new innovative designs! >(smaller?)

This is highly unlikely because the capacitors you would have to use would have to be physically large anyway due to the high voltage alone.  Think about it, if there were truly a better/cheaper/easier way to do this using simple capacitor voltage dividers, then wouldn't all the engineers who design power supplies for a living have figured that out by now?  Instead they only get more complex with things like isolated AC-DC switching regulators, something you should look at purchasing off-the-shelf to do this instead (assuming you are ultimately rectifying to a DC voltage anyway).

If you absolutely need/want a lower AC voltage, please use something like the following on your front end to drastically step down and isolate you from the mains voltage.

https://www.digikey.com/short/3vzzf3

You would have to find one rated for your particular countries line voltage and frequency, as well as of course with the right wall plug.  You could certainly find a physically smaller one as long as it meets your requirements.

Comment: Just FYI: "sic" is used when you leave a quote as-is, without changing the part that is assumed erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

1~2watts is easily doable with double insulated load. Choose Zc(100Hz) @Vrms since the voltage is AC but the load current after a diode bridge twice the frequency  \$C=Amps/(220V*2\pi 100_{Hz})\$  for 0.1A, C=0.72 uF rated at 500V polyurethane (PU ) Polypropylene (PP)or polyester(PE),  self-healing preferred.

The resulting DC needs an e-cap equal to about ESR C = 8 * 10ms. If the loads are nonlinear LEDs then the ESR for 2W depends on number in series and Pd of each, using 4x 0.5W LEDs or 0.15A @14V tells me it is about 2 Ohms and thus e-cap C= 80ms/2 Ohms = 40 mF. which is rather large for 10% voltage ripple.

But if it is a linear load then 14V/0.14A= 100 ohms reducing the E-Cap by 100x in value.

THis is why  it is more effective to use a SMPS. or OFFLINE SMPS at high f so that small C's can be used and use either isolated or non-isolated according to your double insulation requirements.  so for LED's you must remove the need for low ripple unless you can afford a bulky large ecap.

After you understand this then the safety warnings can be observed.

example cap in PP (polypropylene 1%DF at 100Hz)
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/ECW-F6754JL/P12273-ND/656431